# Set QMenu on TopRightCorner in a QMenuBar

Tags: qt, qmenu, qmenubar

can someone explain why this statement does nothing?

```
ui.menuBar->setCornerWidget(ui.menuHelp, Qt::TopRightCorner);
```

`menuBar` is a `QMenuBar` and `menuHelp` is `QMenu`

I still get all my QMenu's clustered on the Left Side of the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a menu to the right side of menu bar, you should add a new `QMenuBar` containing the desired menu as the right corner widget using `setCornerWidget` :

```
QMenuBar *bar = new QMenuBar(ui->menuBar);

QMenu *menuHelp = new QMenu("Help", bar);
bar->addMenu(menuHelp);

ui->menuBar->setCornerWidget(bar);
```